# Ошибки при запуске созданного flutter проекта

Tags: flutter

Создаю новый проект Flutter в Android Studio (дефолтный код, в нем показан счетчик нажатий на кнопку).

Вот код, который я запускаю:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Все создается нормально, но после запуска на эмуляторе в окне Debug в Android Studio появляются следующие ошибки:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
E/flutter ( 5084): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
E/flutter ( 5084): The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: RenderStack#fa065 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:
E/flutter ( 5084):   creator: Stack ← _FloatingActionButtonTransition ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#f065b ink renderer] ← NotificationListener<LayoutChangedNotification> ← PhysicalModel ← AnimatedPhysicalModel ← ⋯
E/flutter ( 5084):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton
E/flutter ( 5084):   constraints: MISSING
E/flutter ( 5084):   size: MISSING
E/flutter ( 5084):   alignment: centerRight
E/flutter ( 5084):   textDirection: ltr
E/flutter ( 5084):   fit: loose
E/flutter ( 5084):   overflow: clip
E/flutter ( 5084): Unfortunately, this object's geometry is not known at this time, probably because it has never been laid out. This means it cannot be accurately hit-tested.
E/flutter ( 5084): If you are trying to perform a hit test during the layout phase itself, make sure you only hit test nodes that have completed layout (e.g. the node's children, after their layout() method has been called).
E/flutter ( 5084): #0      RenderBox.hitTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2102:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #1      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2133:6)
E/flutter ( 5084): #2      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2488:24)
E/flutter ( 5084): #3      BoxHitTestResult.addWithRawTransform (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:801:31)
E/flutter ( 5084): #4      BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:758:12)
E/flutter ( 5084): #5      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2483:33)
E/flutter ( 5084): #6      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:401:12)
E/flutter ( 5084): #7      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #8      RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #9      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #10     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #11     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #12     RenderPhysicalModel.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1722:18)
E/flutter ( 5084): #13     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #14     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #15     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #16     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #17     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #18     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #19     RenderIgnorePointer.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3064:31)
E/flutter ( 5084): #20     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #21     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #22     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #23     RenderFractionalTranslation.hitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2453:22)
E/flutter ( 5084): #24     BoxHitTestResult.addWithRawTransform (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:801:31)
E/flutter ( 5084): #25     BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:758:12)
E/flutter ( 5084): #26     RenderFractionalTranslation.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2447:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #27     RenderFractionalTranslation.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2433:12)
E/flutter ( 5084): #28     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #29     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #31     RenderBox.hi
E/flutter ( 5084): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
E/flutter ( 5084): The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: RenderStack#fa065 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:
E/flutter ( 5084):   creator: Stack ← _FloatingActionButtonTransition ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#f065b ink renderer] ← NotificationListener<LayoutChangedNotification> ← PhysicalModel ← AnimatedPhysicalModel ← ⋯
E/flutter ( 5084):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton
E/flutter ( 5084):   constraints: MISSING
E/flutter ( 5084):   size: MISSING
E/flutter ( 5084):   alignment: centerRight
E/flutter ( 5084):   textDirection: ltr
E/flutter ( 5084):   fit: loose
E/flutter ( 5084):   overflow: clip
E/flutter ( 5084): Unfortunately, this object's geometry is not known at this time, probably because it has never been laid out. This means it cannot be accurately hit-tested.
E/flutter ( 5084): If you are trying to perform a hit test during the layout phase itself, make sure you only hit test nodes that have completed layout (e.g. the node's children, after their layout() method has been called).
E/flutter ( 5084): #0      RenderBox.hitTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2102:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #1      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2133:6)
E/flutter ( 5084): #2      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2488:24)
E/flutter ( 5084): #3      BoxHitTestResult.addWithRawTransform (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:801:31)
E/flutter ( 5084): #4      BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:758:12)
E/flutter ( 5084): #5      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2483:33)
E/flutter ( 5084): #6      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:401:12)
E/flutter ( 5084): #7      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #8      RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #9      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #10     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #11     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #12     RenderPhysicalModel.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1722:18)
E/flutter ( 5084): #13     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #14     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #15     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #16     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #17     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #18     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #19     RenderIgnorePointer.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3064:31)
E/flutter ( 5084): #20     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #21     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #22     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #23     RenderFractionalTranslation.hitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2453:22)
E/flutter ( 5084): #24     BoxHitTestResult.addWithRawTransform (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:801:31)
E/flutter ( 5084): #25     BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:758:12)
E/flutter ( 5084): #26     RenderFractionalTranslation.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2447:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #27     RenderFractionalTranslation.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2433:12)
E/flutter ( 5084): #28     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #29     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2135:11)
E/flutter ( 5084): #30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter ( 5084): #31     RenderBox.hi
I/flutter ( 5269): The value is: true
I/flutter ( 6300): The value is: true
I/flutter ( 6766): The value is: true
I/flutter ( 7592): The value is: true
I/flutter ( 7592): The value is: false
I/flutter ( 7705): The value is: true
I/flutter ( 7705): The value is: false
```

Просто не понимаю что же там сбоит! :(
Android Studio 3.5.3
Flutter version: v1.12.13+hotfix.5

Comment: Вообще ругается на рендер, попробуйте запустить [этот код](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab#step-1-create-the-starter-flutter-app)

Comment: И добавите ваш код который вы пытаетесь запустить

Comment: Спасибо! Добавил.

Comment: @MiT Код по ссылке запускается без ошибок

Comment: `style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1` попробуйте убрать

Comment: @MiT Сработало! Оформите пожалуйста ответ, я отмечу его как правильный. И если можно объяснение, в кратце, чтоб я наконец понял почему происходят эти ошибки :) Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была с `style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1`, термин `display1` устарел (*Material Design 2014*) и не должен использоваться, современный термин `headline4`. Эта функция будет отключена после v1.13.8.

А вот почему проблемы с рендером, я и сам понять не могу. У себя и в [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) воспроизвести не смог... Возможно баг в **v1.12.13+hotfix.5**, так как последняя стабильная версия [v1.12.13+hotfix.7](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases)